# Multiple hased conditionals in relational model giving error "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, relational-database

Our Rails app is getting an SQL error with our relational db model, memberships.

**SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: membership.accepted: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "users"."id" = "memberships"."user_id" WHERE "memberships"."bet_id" = ? AND "membership"."accepted" = 't' AND "membership"."against" = 'f'**

In our app, a user can make a bet (ie "Local sports team wins tonight") and other users can join the bet either as **agree**ing with or **against** the bet.  We model this relationship with memberships, which contain user_id, bet_id, against:boolean, accepted:boolean. A user has_many bets through memberships, and a bet has_many users through memberships who either agree with the bet (agree_members), or are betting against (against_members). Users must request to be accepted into the bet. A user has many bets he agrees with (agree_bets) or is against (against_bets). Here are the models

Models
User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships

   has_many :agree_bets,   -> { where(memberships: { accepted: true, against: false }) }, through: :memberships, source: :bet
   has_many :against_bets, -> { where(memberships: { accepted: true, against: true }) },  through: :memberships, source: :bet

   has_many :membership_requests, -> { where(memberships: { accepted: false }) }, through: :memberships, source: :bet

  def active_bets
    agree_bets | against_bets
  end
end
```

Bet

```
class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :memberships

  has_many :agree_members,   -> { where(membership: { accepted: true }).where(membership: { against: false }) }, through: :memberships, source: :user
  has_many :against_members, -> { where(membership: { accepted: true }).where(membership: { against: true }) },  through: :memberships, source: :user

  has_many :agree_requests,   -> { where(membership: { accepted: false }).where(membership: { against: false }) }, through: :memberships, source: :user
  has_many :against_requests, -> { where(membership: { accepted: false }).where(membership: { against: true }) },  through: :memberships, source: :user
end
```

Membership

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bet
  belongs_to :user
end
```

New to Rails and DBs in general. Any help with my logic or syntax would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `memberships` (note the final `s`) in the `Bet` model as well?

Comment: Fixed! Wow, I feel silly.  Thank you so much for spotting the mistake!